# Mysql, PDO "rank"

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, distinct

I am having some trouble trying to figure out, how to accomplish the following.

My table:

```
id:  schema:  updated_date

1    sometext  2012-01-01
1    sometext  2012-02-02
1    sometext  2011-03-03
1    sometext  2010-04-04
2    sometext  2012-04-05
2    sometext  2012-06-07
2    sometext  2011-04-01
2    sometext  2010-09-09
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is selecting everything from the table, and getting all distinct records based on ids, which should give me two rows, the tricky part is getting the result based on the updated_date, I want the newest one. So based on the above table, I would like to be able to extract the following 2 records:

```
1    sometext  2012-02-02
2    sometext  2012-06-07
```

Can anyone please help me how to make this I MySQL, I am using PHP PDO.

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_schema` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table data:

```
INSERT INTO `mail_schema` (`id`, `name`, `message`, `updated_by`, `last_updated`) VALUES
(1, 'nummer et', '<p>\n med tekst</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:56:21'),
(1, 'nummer 2', '<p>\n  med tekst</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:56:46'),
(1, 'test', '<p>\n  test</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:57:38'),
(1, 'test igen', '<p>\n asd</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:58:28'),
(2, 'test 5', '<p>\n    asd</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:59:11'),
(3, 'test 6', '<p>\n    med id 3</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 18:59:37'),
(2, 'test 5', '<p>\n    asd version 2</p>\n', 3, '2012-06-25 19:00:46');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, I have found this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mail_schema ORDER BY last_updated DESC) AS x GROUP BY id
```

Although it seems kind of ugly, its getting me further.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY updated_date DESC;
```

that didn't work?

Comment: This seems to work, although iam getting the oldest post with each id, instead of the newest. I have tried using ASC instead of DESC without any luck.

Comment: @Mathias it's returning me the correct result, with `id` 2 being displayed first only. [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1af4e/2)

Comment: Iam getting 3 records with this query. I have 7 rows in the table, but only 3 unique ids so thats fine, but it selects the oldest of the 3 rows not the newest ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GROUP BY` clause in an SQL query.

I believe a query like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `id`, `updated_date` DESC ORDER BY `id` ASC
                                                    ^
                                                    Might need to be ASC
```

Comment: Not sure what this does, but it dosen't seem to work, here is my sql from the code (sry for the misinformation regarding the date field):

$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id,name,message,updated_by,last_updated FROM mail_schema GROUP BY id, last_updated ASC ORDER BY id ASC");

This gives me all the records from the table?

Comment: Try adding: `SELECT DISTINCT( id), *` at the beginning instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT( id), * FROM mail_schema GROUP BY id, last_updated DESC ORDER BY id ASC"); gives an empty result

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT( id), * FROM mail_schema ORDER BY last_updated DESC`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM mail_schema ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I'm not thinking straight today, but I'm amazed that this doesn't work: `SELECT * FROM mail_schema GROUP BY id, updated_date DESC`

Comment: It gives me:


SQL query: SELECT * FROM mail_schema GROUP BY id, last_updated DESC LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 7

id name message updated_by last_updated
1 test igen <p>
   asd</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:58:28
1 test <p>
   test</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:57:38
1 nummer 2 <p>
   med tekst</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:56:46
1 nummer et <p>
   med tekst</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:56:21
2 test 5 <p>
   asd version 2</p>
3 2012-06-25 21:00:46
2 test 5 <p>
   asd</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:59:11
3 test 6 <p>
   med id 3</p>
3 2012-06-25 20:59:37

Comment: What if you just run `SELECT * FROM mail_schema GROUP BY id`

Comment: it outputs 3 rows, but in the wrong order, that is it has taken the 3 oldest instead of the 3 newest. Have tried applying DESC and ASC without any luck, it only changes the way the output is displayed, not what output is displayed.

Comment: I'll have to try this for myself in an hour or so, I'll get back to you

Comment: Thank you, i've added the data from the table to my orginal question. Its getting late in my country so maybe, i'll first answer you in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `id` ORDER BY `date`
```